# Crank Nicolson Method PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following PDE 
$$0=\partial _t u+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx} u$$
Now I assume that 
$$t\in[0,T], x\in[0,L]$$ 
and initial data 
$$u(T,x)=g(x), u(t,0)=a(t), u(t,L)=b(t)$$

The grid $$\{(ik,jh): j=1,...,N_t\}$$ with $$h=L/N_x, k=T/N_t$$ is given and we seek approximations $$U_j^i\approx u(ik,jh)$$.
Set $$U^i=(U_j^i)_{j=1,...,N_x}\in R^{N_x-1}$$.

Now I do not understand how to formulate (may you can help me with that) the explicit finite-difference scheme as linear equation $$U^i=FU^{i+1}+p^i$$ for some $(N_x-1)\times(N_x -1)$ matrix $F$ and $p_i\in R^{N_x-1}$

and the fully-implicit finite difference scheme as $$BU^i=U^{i+1}+q^i$$ for matrix $B$ and vector $q^i$ to be determined.

Adding these two equations gives me the Crank Nicolson Method.

Comment: Use the ideas here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Explicit_method

Comment: The difference will be that you have a factor of $1/2$ in your equations

Comment: Start by making a finite grid of say, 4x4 points or so. Write down all the equations for each of the unknowns, and try to put them in a matrix form.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have been looking at wikipedia already but I have some difficulties with the difference in the notation, how would you start here?

Comment: As far as notation goes, it is mostly the same, with the following substitution: they use $u_j^n$, you use $U_j^i$. They still refer to the same variables, i.e., the upper index goes with time, the lower index goes with space. Another difference between your case and the Wikipedia one is that you have boundary data at time $t=T$, not at $T=0$, so your explicit solution will actually march backwards in time from time $t=T$ back towards $t=0$, so that your explicit formulation will follow the Wikipedia implicit, and vice-versa.

Comment: If you know Matlab, the following is useful as well. The form of the matrices is given explicitly in the code. http://www.dynamicearth.de/Lectures/FortgGeodyn.WiSe10/Tutorial/Day2/cranknicholson.pdf

Comment: Thanks again for your comments, would you still mind writing it down in the first case (explicit difference scheme), I will do the rest but want to be sure everything is correct.

Comment: If I get some time, I'll take a crack at writing it up.